# Keep Ad/banner static on application Screens

Tags: android, iphone, admob, iad, ads

After releasing a few apps to Google Play/App Store, I have noticed that the revenue is higher in applications which keep the Ads static (it also increases eCPM).

By static I mean that when you navigate between activities, the Ad stays visible at all times, I achieve that in Phonegap Apps, as they are really one screen hosting a webview.

My question is what is the recomndded technic to achieve that in Native Applications both on IOS and Android.

I am looking for a conceptual solution and thus asking on both platforms.

Thanks!

Udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way Create BaseActivity and declare AdsView object as common in that so by extending this activity you can get single instance.

Another is without creating any BaseActivity declare your AdsView as public static and used in all the screen and add this view in Adsview container means use any empty layout to add this View later on when the screen/activity start with specify layout